# Decision Tree with Tikz - Not to fill and grow down instead of growing west

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to build this decision tree I was take out fill option at

```
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
```

and also make the tree grow down

```
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{bag} = [circle, text width=4em, text centered, draw]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum height=8pt, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, text width=1em, text centered, draw, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, child anchor=west]
\tiny
\node[bag]{XOR}
child {
    node[decision]{TEST}
    child {
        node[bag]{A= 0}
            child{
                node[choice]{}
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=0}
                    child {
                        node[end]{0}
                    }
                }
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=1}
                    child {
                        node[end]{1}
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    child {
        node[bag]{A=1}
            child{
                node[choice]{}
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=0}
                    child {
                        node[end]{1}
                    }
                }
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=1}
                    child {
                        node[end]{0}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. With a few more lines you can make this example fully compilable by copy/pasting :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. The default behaviour is for the tree to grow down. You can make it grow "west" instead with the `grow=left` option.

Comment: My tree grows side ways i want to grow it downwards natural progression, i am very new to latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't give any options, the tree grows downwards, naturally. I have changed

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum height=8pt, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
```

to

```
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, draw, inner sep=0pt]
```

to remove the `fill`. Also you have to use appropriate distances in

```
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=5cm]
```

so that things don't overlap.

Your code becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{bag} = [circle, text width=4em, text centered, draw]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum height=8pt, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, draw, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, text width=1em, text centered, draw, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}%%[grow=left, child anchor=east]
\tiny
\node[bag]{XOR}
child {
    node[decision]{TEST}
    child {
        node[bag]{A= 0}
            child{
                node[choice]{}
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=0}
                    child {
                        node[end]{0}
                    }
                }
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=1}
                    child {
                        node[end]{1}
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    child {
        node[bag]{A=1}
            child{
                node[choice]{}
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=0}
                    child {
                        node[end]{1}
                    }
                }
                child {
                    node[bag]{B=1}
                    child {
                        node[end]{0}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope that helps!